# Get custom field label

Tags: custom-field

I've defined some custom fields using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), and I display these fields as keys and values using `get_post_meta`, e.g.:

```
<span class="campsite_meta_key">מחיר:</span>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);?>
,

<span class="campsite_meta_key">מפה:</span>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'map', true);?>
...
```

This involves code duplication, because the Hebrew name of the field (e.g. `מפה`) is already defined as the custom field *label*.

**Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the a custom field label?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the ACF documentation for [`get_field_object`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field_object/):

```
$field_object = get_field_object( 'price', $post->ID );
echo $field_object['label'];
```

Comment: That's a ACF specific function and doesn't work without the plugin.